# XCode: Shortcut to toggle between Editor and Help Window?

Tags: xcode

Is it possible from a keyboard shortcut to switch from the XCode editor window to help and then back again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both windows belongs to the same application (XCode), I use Command+` to switch between the help and the editor.

Answer (score 2):

If the usual shortcut to switch between windows of the same application does not work for you, check for conflicts in Preferences > Key Bindings

With a german keyboard layout switching between organizer and editor does not work by default because it conflicts with "Edit Scheme...".